# UIImagePickerController - Determine if video was trimmed or edited

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to determine if a video chosen by a user using UIImagePickerController has been trimmed or not?

My app allows users to send short videos to each other. If they record a video whilst in the app, I then save a copy of it back to their gallery so that they can send it easily next time .. I'd like to do the same with trimmed videos but not un-trimmed videos, as that would just lead to duplicates.

I'm using this code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[imagePicker setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
[imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:6];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I've already tried using the NSURL returned to determine if the video is trimmed or not, but sadly even un-trimmed videos come back like this: "trim.DBOnmL.MOV" and having looked through the documentation, I can't find any properties that are helpful.

-- edit

I have implemented imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:, I just don't see any properties returned that let me know if it was edited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this.

imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: returns a url to the original video asset and the trimmed (even if untrimmed) video asset.

You can simply get the duration of the original and the trimmed (even if untrimmed) videos and compare them, if different, it was trimmed.

This gets your both the URLs:

```
    NSURL *originalVideoAssetUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSURL *videoAssetUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

.. and this gets you the duration of an asset

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:assetUrl
                                                 options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                                          AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey,
                                                          nil]];

    NSTimeInterval durationInSeconds = 0.0;
    if (asset) 
        durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method. The info dictionary contains some useful information about whether the image/video is edited by the user or not.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I already have, but don't see any properties returned that let me know if the video was trimmed/edited. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You could load your 2 video clips into NSData for comparison and use the 'length' to compare size. Clipped videos would be less.

Comment: This wouldn't work. The selected video will usually have a different size because it is compressed even if the user does not edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've found a solution that works (for me). I've put it into an answer